# Problemas en acentos con javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Tengo una página .jsp la cual utiliza varios javascript, que están en la misma página, para llenar los select al adicionar un dato. El problema es que cuando se llenan los datos del select con el javascript no me pone las tildes, salen caracteres raros.
Ya añadí en la primera línea del archivo .jsp lo siguiente`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Lo agregué también en el meta

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

En la página todo normal pero cuando utilizo el javascript me da el problema en los acentos.

Este es el select llenado normal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este con el javascript.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: con la imagen solo te podemos dar la razon necesitamos ver tu codigo

Comment: Posiblemente el fichero javascript que importas en el HTML no esté guardado con la codificación UTF-8

Comment: Estoy pensando justo en lo que dijo el usuario `Pablo Lozano`, a lo mejor ese es el problema principal que experimentas.